# Fighting a Nanite Attack on a Biological System

Tags: science-based, biology, nanotechnology

How would you fight a nanite attack on a biological system (preferably one that has already incorporated nanites?

Assume that the setting is 10 to 20 years in the future and nanites are commonly used for medical purposes such as fighting cancer, the delivery of pharmaceuticals, and much more.

You could use this as a specific scenario: However people become ill when a strain nanites of are ingested and scout out the system. The nanite is made of flat DNA sheets to which an enzyme named thrombinis attached. Thrombin is responsible for blood clotting.  The nanite rolled into a tube with thrombin inside punctures blood vessel starving cell.  DNA aptameres are attached to the surface of the [tissue or organ].  The DNA aptamers seek out nucleoin and attach to the surface of the [tissue or organ].  Then the nanobots penetrate the blood vessels that feed to the [tissue or organ] and by unrolling release the thrombin molecules. Which start the clotting process that reduces blood flow to the tumor and starves the tumor (Adapted from: Arizona State University. "Cancer-fighting nanorobots programmed to seek and destroy tumors: Study shows first applications of DNA origami for nanomedicine." ScienceDaily. ScienceDaily, 12 February 2018 [Found Here](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/02/180212112000.htm)).

How would you fight this nanite attack (for this specific scenario or in general? It seems as though you could target and destroy the offending nanites with another strain of nanites; however, what would you do if you could not introduce this new strain?  Could you purge all the nanites from your system and simply start over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have chosen a rocky road, no question.

"The nanite is made of flat DNA sheets" -- stop right there. DNA is ill-adapted to form sheets. You could do with a protein β-sheet (ill suited for large sheets) or something like a large tubulin cylinder (difficult to unroll).

Also, aptameric adhesion to a target cell that specific is unlikely: DNA is not exposed on the cell surface, so you would need to target some specific antigens instead. There are mechanisms to do this (several viruses use them; "genetic injection" is the most "nanite-like" of them).

Your nanites should be more likely akin to a *very* large [Enterobacteria phage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterobacteria_phage_T2). The "mouth" of the nanite is tailored to the target cell, possibly using a two-pronged approach (first you drench the organism with some marker that is differentially processed between normal and target cells, based on reproduction speed or genetic damage in the case of a tumour. Then you tailor the nanite to target cells still exposing the marker). Nanite attaches to the cell, and when it does, it injects the contents of its "lander" payload inside the cell.

How to *stop* that... I'd advise against killing the nanite itself, because you would in all likelihood just flush the contents in the bloodstream. Okay, it would be highly diluted, but you *so* do *not* want a load of (pro)thrombin released into random capillaries, e.g. in the brain.

The simplest path would be to have an antibody targeting the nanite mouth. Once this happens, the nanite is incapable of binding to anything and will just float aimlessly around until it degrades enough that some enterprising lymphocite decides to gobble it up. Or it will just break down on its own, but over a much longer time period, so that the released enzymes will not be that great of a problem.

Same thing with the original "DNA sheet" approach - just stop the tubes from attaching at all, or prevent the sheet from unfolding.

This "counterattack" would not be brought on by nanites though, but by antibodies; and while mouth-targeting antibodies would be specific to the incoming nanites, the sheet unfolding mechanism would be probably common to several strains of nanites (for commercial reasons if nothing else), and so interfering with *that* might disrupt lots of different strains of nanites.

Comment: Would it be possible to "purge" all of the nanites in circulation?

Comment: Well, yes. If they are all of the same kind or expose similar antigens, you could develop a suitable opsonin to mark nanites for removal. Depending on the quantity in circulation, this might be dangerous though. You would probably do this in steps, gradually increasing the opsonin load until all nanites are flushed.